# Land Surface Temperature

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-8

[image: screenshot]

> **Estimation of Land Surface Temperature**
>
> Contact measurements of emissivity values of the surfaces using thermal radiometers and spectral assessment of samples supplementedLST estimation procedures in this study.Since the temperature values obtained as atsatellite temperature Tʙ,referenced to black bodies,the land cover classes were assigned emissivity values derived through field measurements.Thus the emissivity corrected land surface temperatures can be calculated as [8]:

```
St = Tʙ ∕1+ [λ* Tʙ∕ρ]Ιnɛ
λ = Wavelength of emitted radiance,ρ =h * c / σ (1.438 * 10^-2 m K)
h = Planck’s constant (6.626 * 10^-34 Js)
σ = Boltzmann constant (1.38 * 10^-23 J/K, c = velocity of light (2.998 * 10^8 m/s)
```

Source: *[Estimation of Spatial Variability of Land Surface Temperature using Landsat 8 Imagery](http://www.theijes.com/papers/v4-i11/Version-3/D041103019023.pdf)*, P Rajendran, K Mani, 2015 [PDF]

**Can anyone tell which algorithm is used for Land Surface Temperature retrieval?**

Answer (score 2):

Conversion to At-Satellite Brightness Temperature

http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat8_Using_Product.php

> TIRS band data can be converted from spectral radiance to brightness temperature using the thermal constants provided in the metadata file:
>
> T = K2     ln(    K1   +1) Lλ where:
>
> T = At-satellite brightness temperature (K)
>
> Lλ = TOA spectral radiance (Watts/( m2 * srad * μm))
>
> K1 = Band-specific thermal conversion constant from the metadata
>
> (K1_CONSTANT_BAND_x, where x is the thermal band number)
>
> K2 + Band-specific thermal conversion constant from the metadata
>   (K2_CONSTANT_BAND_x, where x is the thermal band number)
>
> Standard Landsat 8 data products provided by the USGS EROS Center
>   consist of quantized and calibrated scaled Digital Numbers (DN)
>   representing multispectral image data acquired by both the Operational
>   Land Imager (OLI) and Thermal Infrared Sensor (TIRS).

This is the tutorial. This website provided a full step-by-step tutorial.

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/06/deriving-temperature-from-landsat-8-thermal-bands-tirs/

You would then need to convert to land temperature using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDQo2a5e7dM

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Already seen the YouTube link you provided. But some portion is not clear to me. I want to know which type of algorithm is that Single Channel, Split Window or radiative transfer ??

Comment: Give us a time in the video so we can check for you.

Comment: No answer still now!

Answer (score 0):

The paper utilized Landsat 5 TM and Landsat 8
OLI for analyzing land use/land cover change and its
impact on land surface temperature in Sundarban Biosphere
Reserve, India. Split window algorithm and spectral
radiance model were used for determining land surface
temperature from Landsat 8 OLI and Landsat 5 TM,
respectively. The land use land cover change analysis
revealed phenomenal increase in the waterlogged areas
followed by settlement and paddy and a decrease in open
forest followed by deposition and water body. The distribution
of average change in land surface temperature
shows that water recorded highest increase in temperature
followed by deposition, open forest and settlement. Overlay
of the transect profiles drawn on land use/land cover
change map over land surface temperature map revealed
that the land surface temperature has increased in those
areas which were transformed from open forest to paddy,
open forest to settlement, paddy to settlement and deposition
to settlement. The study demonstrated that increase in
non-evaporating surfaces and decrease in vegetation have
increased the surface temperature and modified the temperature
of the study area.
Split window algorithm:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301797360_Analyzing_land_surface_temperature_distribution_in_response_to_land_useland_cover_change_using_split_window_algorithm_and_spectral_radiance_model_in_Sundarban_Biosphere_Reserve_India